# Printing from a loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, numbers, factors

I need to print the factors of a perfect number. Here's the gist of my main class:

```
ArrayList<Integer> perfNums = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the upperbound: ");
upperbound = in.nextInt();
for (int i = 1; i <= upperbound; i++) {
     if (isPerfect(i)) { //boolean to check if number is a perfect number
        perfNums.add(i);
     }
}

System.out.println("Perfect numbers between 1 and " + upperbound + " are:");
for (int i = 0; i < perfNums.size(); i++) {
     System.out.print(perfNums.get(i) + " = ");
     printFactor((int)perfNums.get(i));
     System.out.println();
}
```

Here's the *printFactor* class.

```
private static void printFactor(int number){
    int factor = 1;
    while(factor < number){
        if (number%factor == 0) System.out.print(factor+ " + ");
        //I don't know how to print the + sign otherwise.
        factor++;
    }
}
```

And here's a sample output:

```
Enter the upperbound: 10000
Perfect numbers between 1 and 10000 are:
6 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 
28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 + 
496 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 31 + 62 + 124 + 248 + 
8128 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 127 + 254 + 508 + 1016 + 2032 + 4064 +
```

I've got the main gist of it but I've struggled with an output issue. Due to the restrictions of my online submission system, my output needs to fit exact specifications.

**My question is how do I go about printing all the factors of my perfect number but removing the + sign at the end?** (e.g)`6 = 1 + 2 + 3`

I'm not too sure of many methods to print from a while loop. Would a for-loop be better for my goals? Or are there alternative methods to print the factors of a number?

Comment: A for-loop probably  wouldn't help much since it's just another kind of loop. What you could do is collect the factors into a list and then print that list, i.e. loop over it and print a + before each element but the first (or after each element but the last) in the list.

Comment: What about using a `List` then [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)? Or even better, Java 8 streams and `collect()`.

Comment: If you want to use your code: use 2 print statements and print the + first if you printed a factor in one of the iterations before (use a boolean in the method to keep track of that or check the current factor not being 1 since that's always the first).

Comment: adding to what @m0skit0 said, which is probably the best way to do it, the `StringJoiner` is only aviable if you use java 8

Comment: You could print `1` before the loop, start `factor` at `2`, and print `" + "` before each number in the loop.

Comment: how about inserting factors in a list then print upto size-1 using append + for all elements upto size-1 then print ele.get(size); separately at the end

Comment: The Java 8 stream sounds interesting but the school's on older software. Definitely something to consider though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The least amount of change to address this might be something like this:

```
private static void printFactor(int number) 
    System.out.print(1);
    int factor = 2;
    while (factor<number) {
        if (number%factor == 0) System.out.print(" + " + factor);
        factor++;
    }
}
```

1 is always a factor, so you can print that before the loop and then prepend `+` to every subsequent factor.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

You should cache the output you want to print into a `StringBuilder`. Then you are able to remove the last plus sign before you print the whole `String`. It also has a better performance.

```
private static void printFactor(int number)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    int factor = 1;
    while (factor < number)
    {
        if (number % factor == 0)
            output.append(factor + " + ");
        factor++;
    }
    // remove last plus sign
    output.deleteCharAt(output.length() - 1);
    // print the whole string
    System.out.print(output.toString());
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest calling `trim` on `output` before `deleteCharAt`. The point of this is to remove trailing blank space before removing last character (`+`).

Answer (score 2):

Since `factor` starts from value 1 and `number % 1 == 0` will always be true, you might print 1 first and then flip `factor` and `+` in `System.out.print`. Like this:

```
private static void printFactor(int number) {
    if(number > 0) {
        System.out.print(1);
    }
    int factor = 2;
    while (factor<number) {
        if (number % factor == 0) {
            System.out.print(" + " + factor);
        }
        factor++;
    }
}
```

Not the best solution, but it will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a variable String `numb`  and use `substring` method like this:

```
      String numb ="";
        while(factor<number){
            if(number%factor == 0) 
                numb= numb + factor+ " + ";
            factor++;
        }
        System.out.print(numb.substring(0, numb.trim().length()-1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of using Java 8 :)

```
private static void printFactor(int number){
    System.out.println(IntStream.range(1, number)
                                .filter(p -> number % p == 0)
                                .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(i))
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the quick response. You all have been a lifesaver, and I managed to pick up some new things to consider when I code in the future.

Anyway, while waiting for a reply I was fiddling with the code and came up with a rather inelegant solution, if anybody's interested. Here's the changes to the main class:

```
System.out.println("Perfect numbers between 1 and " + upperbound + " are:");
     for(int i=0; i<perfNums.size(); i++){
         System.out.print(perfNums.get(i) + " = ");
         outputString = printFactor2(perfNums.get(i));
         if(outStr.endsWith(" + ")) outStr = outStr.substring(0, outStr.length()-3); 
         //because the submission system would cry foul with even a single extra space
         System.out.println(outStr);
     }
```

And here's the changes to the *printFactor* class:

```
private static String printFactor2(int number){
    String out = "";
    int factor = 1;
    while(factor<number){
        if(number%factor == 0) out += factor + " + ";
        factor++;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Basically, what I did was append the factors to a string, then removing the trailing + sign using the substring method. On hindsight, I probably should've called the substring method inside the printFactor class instead. Something like `return out.substring(0, out.length()-3);` perhaps?

Nevertheless, thanks everyone!